# Mesh adds color instead of texture

Tags: texturing, texture-coordinates

Have a problem where mesh somehow using material in a different way.
I have texture node set up. However the whole mesh is only covered with color instead of it.
Color seems from a texture part.
Have tried to add vertex colors but material shows as expected and the mesh seems to have another color and nothing changes it. s the texture itself is scaled to max somehow.
How to cover the mesh with texture properly?
[image]
Adding this material into a cube or other basic mesh results to a good texturing with a proper placement. At least please give some clues on where to look for or what to look for?

Comment: Hello :). This typically happens when your mesh doesn't have a UV map.

Comment: Press U to unwrap, and maybe choose "cylinder project" for this model?

Comment: The default mapping for an image texture is using UV coordinates. If your object has no UV map, then you need to create one by unwrapping the object, or use a different kind of coordinates. You might want to read the following link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material